# .gitlab-ci.yml how to fixed this config to be better *gitlab-tunner without docker"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

i have this config on my gitlab, this config is work untill i have install some node package and push package.json into gitlab repo, and i got error.

if i just update my /pages/index.vue is work.
i use gitlab-runner with ssh and without docker

this is my config:

```
before_script:
  - echo "Before script"
  - cd /var/www/stagging.domain.com/public_html/client
build:
  stage: build
  script: 
    - echo "Run build"
    - git pull origin dev
    - yarn install
test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo "Run test"
    - git pull origin dev
    - yarn install
    - yarn test
stagging:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - echo "Deploy stagging"
    - git pull origin dev
    - yarn install --production
    - yarn build
  only:
    - dev
  tags:
    - dev
production:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - cd /var/www/domain.com/public_html/client
    - echo "Deploy production"
    - git pull origin master
    - yarn install --production
    - yarn build
  only:
    - master
  tags:
    - master
```

Comment: If you got it to work, what's the question?

Comment: its doesnt work if i install some package on my local host and i update my nuxt config modules, and then push it to gitlb repo, the runner pass until test satge, and i got error at stagging job, because "yarn install" is not install new paskage on server,